# share message in linkedin using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
window.open("https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?text=hello&url=''",   'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
return false.
```

#### Error

> We are sorry. Something unexpected happened and your request could not be completed. Please close this window and try again...

This is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happen when you hit this code

Comment: we are sorry.Something unexpected happened and your request could not be completed. Please close this window and try again...

Comment: yes...that is not working

Comment: can you hit: https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?text=hello&url='www.example.com'

on browser url

Comment: Hit this:  https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?text=hello&url=www.trickyworld.in

Comment: See my update answer

Comment: yes..it works..bt i had a doubt what is meant by www.trickyworld.in?

Comment: trickyword.in is sample url u will use your valid url in place of this.
This url parameter is required .

Comment: ok..thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I think You have pass URL which you want to share on linkedin

```
window.open("https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?text=hello&url=www.trickyworld.in",   'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
return false.
```

You have to pass valide url